# How do I convert a string yyyy/mm/dd to date in bigquery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'm currently selecting a column from a table where the datatype is a string (format yyyy-mm-dd). However, if I select it, the content of what I selected changes. This is what I am currently writing:

```
select 
timestamp(changeMadeDate) as newDate,
eventType,
parameters_name,
membershipstatus,
gender,
platform,
f0_


from reports_temp.tk0415
where parameters_value = 'true'
or parameters_value = 'false'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#timestamp) function is usually used to convert a date string to a TIMESTAMP data type

Try below

```
SELECT '2016-04-15' date_as_string, TIMESTAMP('2016-04-15') AS date_as_timestamp
```